# Error in run of java component

Tags: java, c++, solaris

please can somebody give me hint what may cause this problem? I have program which interact between c++ and java code. Few days ago was everything fine, but now this error appears when i want to run my component.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xfffffd7ffdfa5807, pid=10917, tid=1
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode solaris-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x7a5807]  jni_GetStaticMethodID+0x157
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /export/home/orders/fixnetix_prod/server/core or core.10917
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000002e49800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_vm, id=1, stack(0xfffffd7fff600000,0xfffffd7fffe00000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000002ea1af0, RBX=0x0000000002e49800, RCX=0x00000000ffffffff, RDX=0x0000000002ea1af9
RSP=0xfffffd7fffdff5f0, RBP=0xfffffd7fffdff680, RSI=0x0000000000414f47, RDI=0x0000000002ea1af0
R8 =0xfffffd7ffef52bc0, R9 =0x0000000000003435, R10=0x0000000000000038, R11=0xfffffd7ffd502258
R12=0x0000000002ea1af0, R13=0x0000000000415ff2, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x000000000300de70
RIP=0xfffffd7ffdfa5807, RFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0xfffffd7fffdff5f0)
0xfffffd7fffdff5f0:   0000000000000000 fffffd7ffefb2f14
0xfffffd7fffdff600:   0000000002e4a550 0000000000000000
0xfffffd7fffdff610:   fffffd7ffef8af50 00009b75aabda7b0
0xfffffd7fffdff620:   0000000002e49800 0000000000000000
0xfffffd7fffdff630:   0000000002e49800 0000000002e4a550
0xfffffd7fffdff640:   fffffd7f00000224 fffffd7ffed2c81e
0xfffffd7fffdff650:   fffffd7fffdff670 fffffd7fffdff780
0xfffffd7fffdff660:   fffffd7fffdff778 0000000000a6ae60
0xfffffd7fffdff670:   fffffd7fffdff758 fffffd7fffdff760
0xfffffd7fffdff680:   fffffd7fffdff6e0 000000000040a9ba
0xfffffd7fffdff690:   fffffd7ffef523f0 0000000002e499e8
0xfffffd7fffdff6a0:   0000000700010006 0000000000a6ae60
0xfffffd7fffdff6b0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0xfffffd7fffdff6c0:   fffffd7fffdff778 fffffd7fffdff770
0xfffffd7fffdff6d0:   00000000004521d0 0000000000439920
0xfffffd7fffdff6e0:   fffffd7fffdff850 000000000040f75b
0xfffffd7fffdff6f0:   0000000000000000 fffffd7ffd52a0cd
0xfffffd7fffdff700:   0000000000000028 0000000000452150
0xfffffd7fffdff710:   0000000000433830 0000000000000000
0xfffffd7fffdff720:   0000000000000000 000000000042ec30
0xfffffd7fffdff730:   000000000042ec80 0000000000454440
0xfffffd7fffdff740:   00000000004544b0 0000000000454510
0xfffffd7fffdff750:   000000000042ecd0 000000000042ed20
0xfffffd7fffdff760:   000000000042ed70 000000000042ec80
0xfffffd7fffdff770:   0000000000454440 00000000004544b0
0xfffffd7fffdff780:   0000000000454510 fffffd7ffd5f5440
0xfffffd7fffdff790:   fffffd7fffdff7c0 fffffd7ffd517280
0xfffffd7fffdff7a0:   fffffd7fff3fa320 0000000000426b08
0xfffffd7fffdff7b0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0xfffffd7fffdff7c0:   fffffd7fffdff7d0 fffffd7fff0f969d
0xfffffd7fffdff7d0:   fffffd7fffdff7f0 000000000040a532
0xfffffd7fffdff7e0:   fffffd7fffdff7f0 000000000041105e 

Instructions: (pc=0xfffffd7ffdfa5807)
0xfffffd7ffdfa57e7:   8d 55 9c 49 8b fc e8 3e d3 bd 00 4c 8b e0 4d 85
0xfffffd7ffdfa57f7:   ff 0f 84 7d 05 00 00 4d 85 e4 0f 84 26 05 00 00
0xfffffd7ffdfa5807:   49 8b 3e e8 89 4a 6f 00 85 c0 0f 85 b3 04 00 00
0xfffffd7ffdfa5817:   49 8b 3e e8 21 df dc ff 48 89 45 80 48 85 c0 0f 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000002ea1af0 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000002e49800 is a thread
RCX=0x00000000ffffffff is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000002ea1af9 is an unknown value
RSP=0xfffffd7fffdff5f0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002e49800
RBP=0xfffffd7fffdff680 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000002e49800
RSI=0x0000000000414f47: _lib_version+0x27 in /export/home/orders/fixnetix_prod/server/server at 0x0000000000400000
RDI=0x0000000002ea1af0 is an unknown value
R8 =0xfffffd7ffef52bc0: __1cSJNI_ArgumentPusherG__vtbl_+0x160 in /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0xfffffd7ffd800000
R9 =0x0000000000003435 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000038 is an unknown value
R11=0xfffffd7ffd502258: memcpy+0x748 in /lib/amd64/libc.so.1 at 0xfffffd7ffd4b0000
R12=0x0000000002ea1af0 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000415ff2: __RTTI___+0x832 in /export/home/orders/fixnetix_prod/server/server at 0x0000000000400000
R14=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R15=0x000000000300de70 is an unknown value


Stack: [0xfffffd7fff600000,0xfffffd7fffe00000],  sp=0xfffffd7fffdff5f0,  free space=8189k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x7a5807]  jni_GetStaticMethodID+0x157
C  [server+0xa9ba]  JNIEnv_*createJVM(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >&,const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >&,JavaVM_*)+0xca
C  [server+0xf75b]  main+0x7fb
C  [server+0xa2eb]


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000003034800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=34, stack(0xfffffd7fdee1f000,0xfffffd7fdef1f000)]
  0x0000000003028800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=33, stack(0xfffffd7fdef4c000,0xfffffd7fdf04c000)]
  0x0000000003025800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=32, stack(0xfffffd7fdf04d000,0xfffffd7fdf14d000)]
  0x0000000003023800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=31, stack(0xfffffd7fdf14e000,0xfffffd7fdf24e000)]
  0x0000000003005800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=30, stack(0xfffffd7fdf24f000,0xfffffd7fdf34f000)]
  0x0000000002ffc000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29, stack(0xfffffd7fdf350000,0xfffffd7fdf450000)]
=>0x0000000002e49800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_vm, id=1, stack(0xfffffd7fff600000,0xfffffd7fffe00000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000002ffa000 VMThread [stack: 0xfffffd7fdf451000,0xfffffd7fdf551000] [id=28]
  0x000000000303e800 WatcherThread [stack: 0xfffffd7fded1e000,0xfffffd7fdee1e000] [id=35]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 77312K, used 1331K [0xfffffd7ff3a00000, 0xfffffd7ff9000000, 0xfffffd7ff9000000)
  eden space 66560K, 2% used [0xfffffd7ff3a00000,0xfffffd7ff3b4cd38,0xfffffd7ff7b00000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0xfffffd7ff8580000,0xfffffd7ff8580000,0xfffffd7ff9000000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0xfffffd7ff7b00000,0xfffffd7ff7b00000,0xfffffd7ff8580000)
 ParOldGen       total 176128K, used 0K [0xfffffd7fe8e00000, 0xfffffd7ff3a00000, 0xfffffd7ff3a00000)
  object space 176128K, 0% used [0xfffffd7fe8e00000,0xfffffd7fe8e00000,0xfffffd7ff3a00000)
 PSPermGen       total 22528K, used 2664K [0xfffffd7fe3c00000, 0xfffffd7fe5200000, 0xfffffd7fe8e00000)
  object space 22528K, 11% used [0xfffffd7fe3c00000,0xfffffd7fe3e9a3c0,0xfffffd7fe5200000)

Card table byte_map: [0xfffffd7ffc213000,0xfffffd7ffc2be000] byte_map_base: 0xff7ffd813c2f5000

Polling page: 0xfffffd7ffc420000

Code Cache  [0xfffffd7ff9200000, 0xfffffd7ff9600000, 0xfffffd7ffc200000)
 total_blobs=166 nmethods=0 adapters=136 free_code_cache=48773Kb largest_free_block=49943872

Compilation events (0 events):
No events

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (7 events):
Event: 0.042 Thread 0x0000000002e49800 Threw 0xfffffd7ff3a0add0 at /export/HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-amd64/jdk7u45/229/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp:3991
Event: 0.077 Thread 0x0000000002e49800 Threw 0xfffffd7ff3a4d6a0 at /export/HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-amd64/jdk7u45/229/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.081 Thread 0x0000000002e49800 Threw 0xfffffd7ff3a54a28 at /export/HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-amd64/jdk7u45/229/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.122 Thread 0x0000000002e49800 Threw 0xfffffd7ff3a77378 at /export/HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-amd64/jdk7u45/229/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.135 Thread 0x0000000002e49800 Threw 0xfffffd7ff3a91c20 at /export/HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-amd64/jdk7u45/229/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
Event: 0.135 Thread 0x0000000002e49800 Threw 0xfffffd7ff3a91da0 at /export/HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-amd64/jdk7u45/229/hotspot/src/share/vm/classfile/systemDictionary.cpp:174
Event: 0.135 Thread 0x0000000002e49800 Threw 0xfffffd7ff3a91da0 at /export/HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-solaris-amd64/jdk7u45/229/hotspot/src/share/vm/oops/instanceKlass.cpp:548

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.120 loading class 0x0000000002eefe10
Event: 0.120 loading class 0x0000000002eefe10 done
Event: 0.120 loading class 0x000000000305a2c0
Event: 0.120 loading class 0x000000000305a710
Event: 0.120 loading class 0x000000000305a710 done
Event: 0.120 loading class 0x000000000305a2c0 done
Event: 0.120 loading class 0x0000000003059720
Event: 0.120 loading class 0x0000000003059720 done
Event: 0.122 loading class 0x0000000003032e30
Event: 0.122 loading class 0x0000000003032e30 done


Dynamic libraries:
0x0000000000400000  server
0xfffffd7fff250000  ../lib/libiXAPI.so
0xfffffd7fff150000  ../lib/libToolkit.so
0xfffffd7fff120000  /lib/64/librt.so.1
0xfffffd7ffd800000  /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
0xfffffd7ffd600000  /usr/lib/64/libCstd.so.1
0xfffffd7fff0f0000  /usr/lib/64/libCrun.so.1
0xfffffd7fff070000  /lib/64/libm.so.2
0xfffffd7ffd4b0000  /lib/64/libc.so.1
0xfffffd7ffd3e0000  /lib/64/libnsl.so.1
0xfffffd7fff030000  /lib/64/libsocket.so.1
0xfffffd7fff040000  /lib/64/libxnet.so.1
0xfffffd7fff060000  /lib/64/libpthread.so.1
0xfffffd7ffd3b0000  /lib/64/libaio.so.1
0xfffffd7ffd390000  /lib/64/libmd.so.1
0xfffffd7ffd490000  /usr/lib/64/libsched.so.1
0xfffffd7ffd370000  /lib/64/libdl.so.1
0xfffffd7ffd350000  /lib/64/libm.so.1
0xfffffd7ffd3a0000  /lib/64/libthread.so.1
0xfffffd7ffd320000  /lib/64/libdoor.so.1
0xfffffd7ffd2e0000  /usr/lib/64/libdemangle.so.1
0xfffffd7ffd2b0000  /lib/64/libkstat.so.1
0xfffffd7ffc4d0000  /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
0xfffffd7ffc480000  /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
0xfffffd7ffc450000  /lib/64/libscf.so.1
0xfffffd7ffc430000  /lib/64/libuutil.so.1
0xfffffd7ffc410000  /lib/64/libgen.so.1
0xfffffd7ffc3f0000  /lib/64/libmp.so.2
0xfffffd7ffc380000  /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xloggc:./fixnetics_gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xms256m -Xmx256m 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk/latest
PATH=/export/home/orders/solaris_studio/SolarisStudio12.3-solaris-x86-bin/solarisstudio12.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/csw/bin:/opt/csw/mysql5/bin:/usr/java/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/export/home/orders/SolarisStudio12.3-solaris-x86-bin/solarisstudio12.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/csw/bin:/opt/csw/mysql5/bin:/usr/java/bin:/usr/sfw/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/export/home/orders/fixnetix_prod/lib:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/amd64/server::/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/amd64/server
SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x143991c], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x143991c], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x69cf10], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x69cf10], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x69cf10], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x69cf10], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x1245928], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x00000004
SIGHUP: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGINT: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x1245928], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x00000004
SIG39: [libjvm.so+0x124abf0], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000008
SIG40: [libjvm.so+0x69cf10], sa_mask[0]=0xffbffeff, sa_flags=0x0000000c


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:                    Oracle Solaris 10 1/13 s10x_u11wos_24a X86
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
                            Assembled 17 January 2013

uname:SunOS 5.10 Generic_147148-26 i86pc
  (T2 libthread)
rlimit: STACK 10240k, CORE infinity, NOFILE 65536, AS infinity
load average:0.62 0.51 0.47

CPU:total 16 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 26 stepping 5, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 33545320k(2967752k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08) for solaris-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_45-b18), built on Oct  8 2013 06:06:53 by "" with Sun Studio 12u1

time: Thu Mar  5 08:29:55 2015
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: Looks like your JNI stopped working. Were there any updates to any C++ plugins/Dynamic Libraries that JNI was used to call?

Comment: No there was no update. I have same component that run on other solaris machine and everything run fine, but on this particular server i have this error.